# How to change css of one class when hovering over another?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am new to css especially combinators but I am trying to change css of a p element when hovering over a h1 element both of which are in a div of class "a"
but I can't figure out how to do it.Here is my code

HTML

```
<div class="a">
<h1>This is a Heading</h1>
<p>This is a paragraph.</p>
</div>
```

CSS

```
div.a h1:hover ~ div.a p {color:red;}
```

So what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Try `div.a h1:hover ~  p{color:red;}` example https://jsfiddle.net/0vkusf5f/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to target the `div` element again.

**All Paragraphs** [**JsFiddle Demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/0vkusf5f/)

**First Paragraph** [**Jsfiddle Demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/0vkusf5f/1/)

```css
div.a h1:hover~p{color:red;}
```

```html
<div class="a">
<h1>This is a Heading</h1>
<p>This is a paragraph.</p>
<p>This is a paragraph.</p>
</div>
<p>Some other text.</p>
```

If you only want to target the first `<p>` paragraph tag then you can use

```css
div.a h1:hover+p{color:red;}
```

```html
<div class="a">
<h1>This is a Heading</h1>
<p>This is a paragraph.</p>
<p>This is a paragraph.</p>
</div>
```

If you have any questions about the source code above please leave a comment below and I will get back to you as soon as possible.

I hope this help. Happy coding!

Answer (score 2):

This solution should work :

```
div.a > h1:hover + p {
    color:red;
}
```

`> h1:hover` to select h1:hover element where the parent is div with class 'a'

`+ p` to select p element that are placed immediately after h1:hover element

Answer (score 1):

If you are using jQuery you may use the following code to transform the paragraph.

```
$('div.a h1').hover(function() {
        $(this).siblings('p').css(color: red;);
    }, function() {
        $(this).siblings('p').css( << Previous Css >> );
    }
});
```